# Current Format of excel getting changed in Closedxml SaveAs method

Tags: c#, .net, excel

In my C# application, I am using ClosedXml .Excel for working with excel files.
I have an excel template, where I add the template into application and add data to the excel sheet and save the excel as below,

```
wb = new XLWorkbook(exportOption.FileName);
---
if (wb.Worksheets.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < wb.Worksheets.Count; i++)
    {
        using (var ws = wb.Worksheet(i + 1))
        {
            if (ws.Visibility == XLWorksheetVisibility.Visible)
            {
                ws.SetTabActive();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

try
{
    wb.CalculateMode = XLCalculateMode.Auto;
    wb.SaveAs(exportOption.FileName);
}
```

After saving the changes my excel format completely changes with other sheets as well.
For example, In one sheet i have percentage format which changes to Date format.
How can i keep the format of excel same and just insert data to other sheets.

Comment: Show us how you are setting values in the spreadsheet. Also I take it you are not specifying any cell formats, does explicitly setting cell formats make a difference?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have a xlsm file which I just open and save with ClosedXML. Some formatting is destroyed and also is the file size smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Its common for Excel to be tricked into treating numbers as dates (as under the hood Excel stores dates as numbers). To force the cell to be a number not date try:

```
ws.Cell(row,col).SetValue<double>(Convert.ToDouble(val));
```

---

Here is the official documentation on [ClosedXML Cell Formatting](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumberFormatId%20Lookup%20Table&referringTitle=Styles%20-%20NumberFormat).
If you need preserve the format as percentage, eg as "#**.**##%" simply set the cell format:

```
ws.Cell(row, col).Style.NumberFormat.NumberFormatId = 10;
```

*<sub>or untested</sub>*

```
ws.Cell(row, col).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.0%";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I will not be knowing what is the format included in the excel sheet. So the issue is when I save the excel back I want to preserver the formats which applied in the sheet which I am not manipulating.

Comment: *Sorry I'm not 100% understanding.* Can you please [edit] your question to include  screenshots to show issue?

Answer (score 0):

You must select the cell Number Format from your app before saving it.
CLosedXml is a library based on OPENXML library so you must apply an OpenXml excel style Sheet to change Cells Number Format.

This is an [Article](http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/11/09/how-to-create-stylesheet-in-excel-open-xml/) that may help you